# Como descargar un archivo excel con mvc core y c#

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core-mvc

Buen día.

Espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema, tengo que crear y descargar un archivo excel a partir de una consulta, hasta el momento eso lo hace bien, el problema viene cuando publico mi código en el servidor, el archivo lo crea directamente ahí(en el servidor) y ya no se descarga del lado del cliente, lo que necesito es que los usuarios puedan descargar el archivo a su pc.

no se que estoy haciendo mal o que me está faltando, por eso pido su ayuda.

el código de mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ExportarExcel(int cveRMS, DateTime FechaIni, DateTime FechaFin)
        {
CrearCarpetaReportes();


            var nombreExcel = string.Concat("Reporte de Cajas Operativas" + ".xlsx");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(list))
            {
                table.Load(reader);
            }

            table.Columns.Remove("FechaIni");
            table.Columns.Remove("FechaFin");
            table.Columns.Remove("Message");


            using (var libro = new XLWorkbook())
            {

                table.TableName = "Cajas";
                var hoja = libro.Worksheets.Add(table);
                hoja.ColumnsUsed().AdjustToContents();
                libro.SaveAs("C:\\Reportes/Reporte de Cajas Operativas.xlsx");

                //OpenMicrosoftExcel("C:\\Reportes/Reporte de Cajas Operativas.xlsx");
                Download(nombreExcel);

                string physicalPath = "C:\\Reportes/Reporte de Cajas Operativas" + ".xlsx";
                byte[] pdfBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(physicalPath);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
                return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

            }
        }
        public void CrearCarpetaReportes()
        {
            string folderPath = @"C:\Reportes";
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);

            }
        }
        public static void OpenMicrosoftExcel(string FileName)
        {
            var proceso = new Process();
            proceso.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName)
            {
                UseShellExecute = true
            };
            proceso.Start();
        }
```

estoy omitiendo la parte de la consulta donde se pasan los datos al datatble ya que con eso no hay problema.

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: En vez de guardarlo a un directorio y después guardarlo en memoria, mejor crea el archivo en memoria directamente y eso lo retornas. 

Solo omite la parte de guardarlo en un directorio.


libro.SaveAs(ms);
ms.Position = 0;

Comment: @MarcosGuerrero gracias por contestar, de hecho lo tenia así al inicio no lo guardaba físicamente, pero igual no lo descargaba, por eso opté por crear la carpeta, guardarlo y abrirlo pero me encontré con el inconveniente que al publicar el código en el servidor no lo hace del lado del cliente solo en el servidor